# Is authentication necessary when deploying an OAuth2.0 authorization system?

Tags: oauth

It's been clearly mentioned in the OAuth official website that the OAuth is an **authorization** protocol instead of, and should not be considered as an **authentication** protocol. Here I'm confused about this, how can OAuth **authorize** users if it doesn't **authenticate** them in the first place.

Another question is: I'm desiging APIs to provide web services for users. If I use OAuth2.0, do I need a login system? If so, how to build this login system?

Comment: Did you read this: https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorization (in the context of OAuth) includes authentication as one of its steps, but the OAuth specification ([RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)) intentionally avoids discussing how to authenticate a user.

As a result, you can choose any authentication method as you like. For example,

- ID & password (most typical)
- Fingerprint
- Iris recognition
- Random table
- One-time password

So, your understanding is correct. You need a login system (or whatever which can identify a user) for authentication. The OAuth specification leaves authentication to you.